# Using Mailman, how to unshunt message back into hold queue for moderation?

Tags: mailman

How can I get Mailman to reprocess messages in a queue directory? Or alternately, how can I transfer all the messages from a queue directory into the moderation hold queue for the relevant list(s)?

---

My problem is that my `in` queue directory is full of messages that previously passed moderation, but were never delivered because my `qrunner` wasn't working. I know that I could just start up the qrunner and those messages would get delivered, but I want list administrators to have a second look because some of the messages are fairly old, and it wouldn't make sense to send them now.

I read about a Mailman command called `unshunt` but I don't think it does quite what I need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get Mailman to reprocess messages as if they were fresh. First I used `show_qfiles` to extract the raw message content from a .pck file, then I pass that content to the Mailman wrapper.

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/mailman/bin:/usr/lib/mailman/mail"
show_qfiles -q /PATH/TO/YOURFILE.PCK | sudo -u postfix mailman post LISTNAME
```

The `sudo` is required because the Mailman wrapper must be run with a low privileged user like Postfix.

The verb `post` instructs the wrapper to process the message like any other incoming message.

*This doesn't guarantee a message will be held for moderation, it just means the same criteria will be applied as if a new message was sent to the list.*